# MySQL + hugepages + memlock

Tags: mysql, linux, huge-pages

I've successfully configured my Ubuntu server so MySQL can use hugepages. Problem is when I want to enable `memlock` option in `my.cnf` and `/proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_shm_group` is set to another group (MySQL is a member of this group).

```
# uname -a
Linux hostname 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

# egrep ^Huge /proc/meminfo
HugePages_Total:   15000
HugePages_Free:    15000
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0

# id mysql
uid=107(mysql) gid=113(mysql) groups=113(mysql),117(hugetlb)
```

If `/proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_shm_group` is set to `113` everything goes well no matter of `memlock` option.

But if I set `/proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_shm_group` to `117` it works only without the `memlock` option. If I enable it I get this error when MySQL starts:

> InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 21978152960 bytes. errno 1
>
> InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with `ulimit`. Settings in `/etc/security/limits.conf` are ignored so I got it working with simple edit in `/etc/init/mysql.conf`:

```
exec /usr/bin/mysqld
```

changed to

```
script
    ulimit -l unlimited
    /usr/bin/mysqld
end script
```

Comment: `/etc/security/limits.conf` might be ignored because you need to add to  both `/etc/pam.d/common-session` and `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` the line `session required pam_limits.so` ... and then your group `@ hugetlb` in limits conf.